# Why does my Post Request fail when deployed on Google's GAE, but works fine locally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, gcloud, fetch-api

I am making the following GET request to my NodeJS server

```
document.getElementById("login_submit").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    let password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    let requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({email, password})
    }
 
    fetch("/login", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        if (data.error_description) {
            alert("Wrong email or password.");
        }
        else {
            // received a token
            let token = data.id_token;
            let userId = data.id.sub
            console.log(userId, token)

            fetch("/generateJwt/profile?" + new URLSearchParams({token, userId}))
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                window.location.assign(res.url);
            })
        }
    });
})
```

When I run my application locally on localhost, it works perfectly fine. But when I try running my application (specifically this part) on Google's App Engine, I get the following errors.

[image: status 502 and syntax error]

This is how my route looks on the server side that handles the login.

```
login.post('/', function (req, res) {
    const username = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: `https://${DOMAIN}/oauth/token`,
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        body:
        {
            grant_type: 'password',
            username: username,
            password: password,
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET
        },
        json: true
    };
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
            res.status(500).send(error);
        } else {
            console.log(parseJwt(body.id_token));
            let userId = parseJwt(body.id_token);
            let data = {
                id: userId,
                id_token: body.id_token
            }
            res.json(data);
        }
    });

});
```

And my parseJwt function is below. In VS code it says that atob should never be used in new code? Could this be the problem when deployed on GAE?

```
function parseJwt(token) {
    var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
    var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
    var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(atob(base64).split('').map(function (c) {
        return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));

    return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
};
```

Comment: 1) Your POST request is returning HTTP 502 which is an error as in "service not available". 2) The syntax error is most likely caused because the server returns HTML or XML along with the 502 status code. 3) Review the logs for the application that returned 502. 4) You are showing the code for `login.post` for the route `/` but your client is making a POST request to `/login`.

Comment: It says atob is not defined in the logs! Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/atob

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're not sending proper JSON in your POST request. Your post request should be

```
     body: JSON.stringify({'email':email, 'password':password})
```

Comment: But why would this work locally and not on the cloud?

Comment: Your Dev environment might not necessarily be an exact replica of production - your dev env could be using a different version of Node from Production, you could be using a version of a library that is more forgiving of errors than the version on the cloud. As far as I know (always willing to be corrected), JSON.stringify needs an object. The error message about unexpected token < in JSON is usually indicative of malformed JSON